# I am getting error while converting my next js project to docker

Tags: docker, next.js

I'm trying to convert my Next js project to Docker. The Dockerfile I got from the next js github page worked fine for me and I got a build successfully.

```
# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM node:16-alpine AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM node:16-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .
RUN yarn build

# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM node:16-alpine AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production

RUN addgroup -g 1001 -S nodejs
RUN adduser -S nextjs -u 1001

# You only need to copy next.config.js if you are NOT using the default configuration
# COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./
COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json

# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
# COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000

# Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage.
# Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

I wrote this later.

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 imagename
```

Then I faced such error and I can't solve it.

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/app/server.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

I searched a lot on the internet but couldn't find much. What do you think I should do?

Comment: I made node version 14, I deleted next js from package.json file and after npm install in Dockerfile I added this command RUN npm i next@12.0.8-canary.7 I installed lower version. COPY --from=builder /app/.env ./ I added this command. COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./ I commented out this command

After these it worked for me.

Answer (score 70):

Ensure that you're copying all files from the example. In this case you need to ensure you have added or customized `next.config.js` with this:

```js
module.exports = {
  output: 'standalone'
}
```

You'll notice the file is also defined in the examples: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-docker/next.config.js

Comment: I added this setting. The problem is not caused by that. So it seems.

Answer (score 24):

The answer depends on which version of Next you are running.  First of all, you need to uncomment the line in your `Dockerfile` that copies `server.js` (and the rest of the `.next/standalone` folder) to /app.

```
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
```

Then you need to include one of the following in your `next.config.js` files, depending on the version of Next you are running.

If you are running Next `12.1.x` or *earlier*, then you need this:

```
module.exports = {
  experimental: {
    outputStandalone: true,
  },
}
```

If you are running `12.2.x` or later, use this:

```
module.exports = {
  output: 'standalone',
}
```

This will cause .next/standalone to be created, and that folder includes `server.js` so that when the `COPY` command runs, it and the subfolders get placed into `/app`.

Comment: If anyone is interested I done a blog post on this, detailing the space saved when using standalone support on an example application with CMS integration ~80% saving they advised was extremely accurate. https://www.dave-beaumont.co.uk/2022/02/22/reducing-the-dockerized-image-size-of-a-next-js-kontent-integrated-website-with-next-standalone-functionality-in-v12-1/

Comment: Not working even for Next 13.2.3

Answer (score 3):

```
FROM node:14-alpine AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install --frozen-lockfile
RUN npm i next@12.0.8-canary.7

# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM node:14-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .
RUN yarn build

# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM node:14-alpine AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production

RUN addgroup -g 1001 -S nodejs
RUN adduser -S nextjs -u 1001

# You only need to copy next.config.js if you are NOT using the default configuration
COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./
COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json
COPY --from=builder /app/.env ./

# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000

# Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage.
# Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

Solved my problem this is the new Dockerfile and it works for me.

Comment: Would you explain what have you changed so it would be more helpful for people having same issue??

Comment: yarn.lock I am not copying this file. I removed next js from package.json file. I saw that there are problems in the last version, so RUN npm i next@12.0.8-canary.7 I am installing this version from outside. I don't do yarn install I did npm install. I pulled the node version from 16 to 14. COPY --from=builder /app/.env ./ I added this command and copied the env file. COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./ I uncommented this line.

Comment: Hi Batuhan Zorbey Zengin - If you are having npm and not yarn, can you explain why are you using RUN yarn build in your docker file to build the package? should it not be npm run build command instead?. Also, I have done the same but It seems like the .next/standalone folder is not created, and hence, the copy operation fails for me. rather I have tried to copy the entire. next folder like COPY /app/.next ./.next but that also not working. any information?

Answer (score 2):

Just change `nextjs` version in package.json file to `latest` and run `yarn install`. Now docker build work fine.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**
My next is version 11, `with-docker` example is version 12.

I've looked at the history of the Dockerfile in the official Next.js `with-docker` [example](https://github.com/ijjk/next.js/commits/73f3bc7bb9c7d97dc95be0c4e6bb0aaf20b8e462/examples/with-docker/Dockerfile). There I've noticed the addition of these [lines to the Dockerfile](https://github.com/ijjk/next.js/commit/95501c4bed91893ea9614566cf4ad7eb838c989d), and the addition of experimental flag `outputStandalone`.

This flag is available from `next@12` while my project is `next@11`, so undoing these lines in my Dockerfile solved the issue.

Going over that file history can give insight on different issues.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and the conflict was that I was using Next 11 instead 12, you can use [this dockerfile](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/v12.0.8-canary.1/examples/with-docker/Dockerfile) which runs perfect with Next 11 or try the following code.

```
# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM node:14-alpine AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM node:14-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
RUN yarn build

# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM node:14-alpine AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production

RUN addgroup -g 1001 -S nodejs
RUN adduser -S nextjs -u 1001

# You only need to copy next.config.js if you are NOT using the default configuration
# COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./
COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next ./.next
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000

# Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage.
# Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

CMD ["node_modules/.bin/next", "start"]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you still having issues with Next 14 or newer versions this fixed the problem

`NEXT_PRIVATE_STANDALONE=true npm run build`

You can also include this in your dockerFile as well

```
... other stages
FROM base as BUILDER

ENV NEXT_PRIVATE_STANDALONE true

COPY --from=DEPENDENCIES /src/application/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

RUN npm run build
...other stages
```

To this day this is the only solution that works, Nextjs 14 seems to ignore the `output: 'standalone'` configuration

Comment: For Next.js 14 this seems to be the correct answer. Build configuration in `next.config` is ignored.

Comment: Also chech `trustHost: true` for `NextAuthConfig`, if you deploy to production behind trusted proxy https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/10224#issuecomment-1979533431

Comment: Also make sure to add PATH `/api/auth` to your `AUTH_URL` variable, not just FQDN https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/10081#issuecomment-1956320897

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using a `next.js` image so I needed to install the `sharp` [module](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/sharp-missing-in-production) also.

Answer (score 0):

I am using nextJs 13.1.1 and facing same issue when trying with docker and `output: 'standalone'`. It seems mounted folders in container and files are facing this Module not found error if not specified in docker volumes.

```
 volumes:
  - /usr/src/app/build
```

I added build as volume in docker compose and moved standalone and rest of the content to build in place of root of the working directory. Now it's working.

```
COPY --from=build_stage /usr/src/app/package*.json ./build
COPY --from=build_stage /usr/src/app/public ./build/public
COPY --from=build_stage /usr/src/app/next.config.js ./build
COPY --from=build_stage /usr/src/app/.env* ./build

COPY --from=build_stage --chown=appuser:appcontainer /usr/src/app/.next/standalone ./build
COPY --from=build_stage --chown=appuser:appcontainer /usr/src/app/.next/static ./build/.next/static
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was **Mounted** path. Please check Your: `docker-compose.yml` file for possibly collision with mounting points at file's part: `volumes`.
*Simple, but it takes me time to find it ☺️*

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Nextjs with `page` router then you need to add this code to the `next.config.js` file

```
module.exports = {
  output: 'standalone'
}
```

if you are using `app` router then you need to add this code to the `next.config.mjs` file

```
const nextConfig = {
  output: 'standalone'
};

export default nextConfig;
```