NextJS Standalone build dont produce .next/standalone dir inside Docker builder. Works outside it
I'm trying to build NextJS using Docker - using standalone output option.
Now I'm trying to create production build (Dockerfile made from the example one).
It worked lately both in the container and on my machine.
But suddenly it stopped working in Docker, standalone/server.js became missing. So it fails on the COPY .../server.js command.
But when I tried the same command on my machine, the .next/standalone dir was ok.
Version: "next": "^14.2.3",.
My next.config:
const withNextIntl = require("next-intl/plugin")();

module.exports = withNextIntl({
    // TODO: remove eventually if found error with useTranslation and TS
    output: "standalone",
    typescript: {
        ignoreBuildErrors: true,
    },
});

Docker-compose.yml:
  nextapp:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/nextjs/Dockerfile_prod
      args:
        - DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}@db:3306/${DB_DATABASE}
        - UID=${UID}
        - GID=${GID}
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
      - NEXTAUTH_URL=${NEXTAUTH_URL}
      - DATABASE_URL=mysql://${DB_USER}:${DB_PASSWORD}@db:3306/${DB_DATABASE}
      - GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=${GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}
      - GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET=${GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET}
      - GITHUB_CLIENT_ID=${GITHUB_CLIENT_ID}
      - GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET=${GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET}
      - AUTH_SECRET=${SECRET}
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:3000:3000" # keep the IP exact, otherwise it overrides the firewall
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
      goapp:
        condition: service_started

And finally Dockerfile_prod, without the runner stage, I've modified to know more about .next/ dir content:
FROM node:alpine AS base

### Dependencies ###
FROM base AS builder

# allow prisma to use the DATABASE_URL env variable
WORKDIR /app

# fix `cannot find module server.js, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70608086/i-am-getting-error-while-converting-my-next-js-project-to-docker
ENV NEXT_PRIVATE_STANDALONE=true

COPY ./frontend-next ./frontend-next/package.json ./frontend-next/yarn.lock ./frontend-next/localazy.json ./frontend-next/prisma ./

# fix for "Caching failed for pack" error
RUN rm -rf node_modules

# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat tzdata git openssh-client && \
    yarn config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org && \
    yarn --force --frozen-lockfile && \
    yarn global add typescript next react react-dom prisma @localazy/cli

RUN npx prisma generate && \
    localazy download && \
    yarn build && \
    pwd && ls -la ./.next/ && ls -la ./.next/standalone

The build command with output finally resolves in this output saying there's no standalone output;
ERROR [nextapp builder 5/5] RUN npx prisma generate &&     localazy download &&     yarn build &&     pwd && ls -la ./.next/ && ls -la ./.next/standalone               22.8s
------                                                                                                                                                                            
 > [nextapp builder 5/5] RUN npx prisma generate &&     localazy download &&     yarn build &&     pwd && ls -la ./.next/ && ls -la ./.next/standalone:                           
0.848 (node:7) ExperimentalWarning: CommonJS module /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/debug/src/node.js is loading ES Module /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/supports-color/index.js using require().                                                                                                                                       
0.848 Support for loading ES Module in require() is an experimental feature and might change at any time                                                                          
0.848 (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
# ...
3.759 $ next build
4.837 Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
4.837 This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
4.837 You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
4.837 https://nextjs.org/telemetry
4.837 
4.923   ▲ Next.js 14.2.18
4.923 
5.158    Creating an optimized production build ...
7.183 (node:97) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
7.183 (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
22.57 <w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Caching failed for pack: Error: Unable to snapshot resolve dependencies
22.75 Done in 19.07s.
22.77 /app
22.77 total 1076
22.77 drwxrwxr-x    1 root     root          4096 Nov 15 10:50 .
22.77 drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Nov 15 10:19 ..
22.77 drwxrwxr-x    4 root     root          4096 Nov 15 09:14 cache
22.77 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root            20 Nov 15 10:50 package.json
22.77 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root          3895 Nov 15 10:50 routes-manifest.json
22.77 drwxr-xr-x    5 root     root          4096 Nov 15 10:50 server
22.77 drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Nov 15 10:50 static
22.77 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root       1057686 Nov 15 10:50 trace
22.77 drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Nov 15 10:50 types
22.77 ls: ./.next/standalone: No such file or directory
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npx prisma generate &&     localazy download &&     yarn build &&     pwd && ls -la ./.next/ && ls -la ./.next/standalone" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

Anyone have met this guy and knows how to fix it? Thanks for any advice

Please have a look at the Vercel Next-example here that I'm using: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-docker/Dockerfile

I don't see the difference. My dockerfile was based on this one and I've checked it already. Can you please suggest what am I missing?

I've rewritten the Dockerfile from the newer example Dockerfile and it works. Thanks.
